# How to get struct from objective-c function using ObjCRuntime c#

Tags: c#, objective-c, .net-maui

How to get struct value from objective-c function using ObjCRuntime c#, for example CoreGraphics.CGRect. I try to use next:

```
var handle = RuntimeInterop.IntPtr_objc_msgSend(objectHandle, selectorHandle);
Dlfcn.GetCGRect(handle, "");
```

but handle always is 0x0

Comment: You might raise an issue to Microsoft similar to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7778

Comment: the question is not about